# How can I determine if a char* is a windows line ending?

Tags: c, windows, newline, carriage-return

In my C program, I am looking through a file character by character for info. For some reason my data is getting windows line ending characters even though my code looks like it does below.

I have tried a couple of things like temp[0]=='\r\n'

```
while((temp = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
    if((temp>=65 && temp<=90) || (temp>=97 && temp<=122) || (temp>=48 && temp<=57) || temp==39){
      c[count]=temp;
      count++;
    }
else
      break;
```

Comment: "\r\n" is two characters.

Comment: A Windows line terminator is *two* characters, not one.  (And `'\r\n'` is *one* integer that is probably unequal to both of the two characters in question.)

Comment: @JGroven, `"\r\n"` is one array containing three characters, including the terminator.  But that's not what the OP says they used.

Comment: I suggest doing `temp >= 'A'` and similarly for the rest. This will make the intent of your code much more clear when others look at it, including you at some future date.

Comment: How do the windows line endings affect the result of your code? In most cases, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hint: don't use magic numbers: `65` -> `'A'`, `90` -> `'Z'` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Windows line endings consist of two separate characters, a carriage return (`'\r'`) immediately followed by a newline (`'\n'`).  Because they are a combination of two characters, you cannot detect them by looking at only one character at a time.

If your code is running *on* Windows and the file is supposed to be interpreted as text, then open it in text mode (for instance, `"r"` instead of `"rb"`), and the line terminators should be automatically translated to single newlines.  If you're running on a system that uses single newlines as line terminators (most anything *but* Windows these days) then no such translation will be performed.  In that case, to detect Windows-style line terminators you need to keep track of whether the immediately previous character was a `'\r'`.  When that is so, and the next character read is a `'\n'`, then you've detected a line terminator.

But if it should be considered erroneous for Windows-style terminators to be in the file, then consider instead just fixing the file via `dos2unix` or a similar utility.